# Is SproutCore suitable for mobile app development?

Tags: mobile, sproutcore

by using it with something like PhoneGap, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See for example [SproutCore and PhoneGap](http://blog.sproutcore.com/sproutcore-and-phonegap/).